# Analyzing a Login Process

Tags: binary-analysis, debugging, dynamic-analysis

I am reverse engineering a program that uses a custom auth protocol. This is a basic outline of the process:

1. Client takes input for username and password, then sends username to the auth server.
2. Auth server calculates a public key and responds with it.
3. Client uses that key to calculate a session key, which is sent to the server.

The communication is all done via HTTP. My goal is to locate and analyze the functions responsible for calculating the session key. My most recent approach was to set a breakpoint on `ws2_32.recv`, begin the login process, then step through the execution from the recv breakpoint to analyze how the public key was being used to calculate the session key.

However, the breakpoint isn't triggered at the expected time. A breakpoint on `ws2_32.send` is triggered as expected. I'm pretty stumped on this. Is there something I've overlooked? Is there a better approach to locating the functions?

Comment: Is the client a (windows) executable? You could look at what the executable imports in the Import Address Table or run it through a disassembler.

Answer (score 1):

Your program might be using `ws2_32.recvfrom` instead of `ws2_32.recv`. Or alternatively, it could be using one of the lower-level Winsock functions, such as `ws2_32.WSARecv`, `ws2_32.WSARecvEx`, `ws2_32.WSARecvFrom`, or `ws2_32.WSARecvMsg`.

You may want to try one of the following approaches to determine what the program is doing:

- Use an API monitor such as [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) to determine what networking functions are called.
- Use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to capture the network-receive events and double-click on those events to see the callstack.

Comment: I took a look at the process with API monitor and monitored all functions under "networking". I also set individual breakpoints on `recv`, `recvfrom`, `WSARecv`, `WSARecvEx`, and `WSARecvFrom`. Though the auth library calls `send`, it never seems to call any of the recv functions listed. The only calls to `recv` are from `libcef.dll`, and the calls are out of order in relation to the auth library's `send` calls. I'm watching the recv packets come in simultaneously using network monitor, too. Also, `WSARecvMsg` isn't recognized by API Monitor nor Immunity Debugger for me.

Comment: Sounds like using Process Monitor is the way to go, then.