# Reverse Referencing in IDA

Tags: ida

I'm trying to reverse-engineer a binary. I'm interested to find its network traffic but dynamic analysis is failing. Using IDA I'm able to identify network calls but when I try to reverse its caller using `x` shortcut after couple of callers I get stuck at this point:

```
.text:00407230                 dd offset sub_40600C
.text:00407234                 dd offset sub_403C30
.text:00407238                 dd offset nullsub_4
.text:0040723C                 dd offset sub_40601C
.text:00407240                 dd offset sub_4039BC
.text:00407244                 dd offset sub_40C294
```

I would like to ask how I can proceed further.

Comment: See the Process Monitor comment at http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/11529/1562.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that these functions are called indirectly (if ever called at all).
If this program is written in something like C++ this may be a virtual function pointer table, and anyway such code organization usually represents table of functions used by indirect calls.

If this program is written in C++ I'd suggest to read [this presentation](http://www.hexblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Recon-2011-Skochinsky.pdf) by @Igor Skochinsky - this is very educational reading.

I'd proceed as follows:

- Find a references to the specific address where function address is stored.
- If there is no one referencing it look for the first address before the one you are working with referenced by something and inspect all references to it.
- You'll probably find there indirect call of one of the functions from the table or initialization of virtual function pointer table in the instance of the class.

Comment: Thank you. I've read the presentation and it is very helpful. I'll try to dig more into it.